# an't access lexical declaration 'myInput' before initialization

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my html file I've got script imports:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="myInput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
</head>
```

`myInput.js` has namespace and class defined:

```
let myinput = module.exports = {};

myinput.MYInput = class {
    constructor(params) {...}

myinput.init = (params) => {
    return new myinput.MYInput(params)
}
```

and I'd like to use it in my `example.js` file:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    let this_input = myinput.MYInput.init({...})
```

Unfortunately the result is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:63342/myinput/myinput.js:1
myinput.js:1:15
GEThttp://localhost:63342/favicon.ico
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 4ms]

ready! example.js:2:13
jQuery.Deferred exception: can't access lexical declaration 'myinput' before initialization @http://localhost:63342/myinput/example.js:6:19
e@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30005
l/</t<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30307
setTimeout handler*l/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30516
c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:28294
fireWith@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:29039
fire@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:29075
c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:28294
fireWith@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:29039
ready@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:32012
B@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:31791
EventListener.handleEvent*@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:32160
@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:220
@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:225
 undefined jquery.min.js:2:31560
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'myinput' before initialization
    <anonymous> http://localhost:63342/myinput/example.js:6
    jQuery 13
```

I've tried importing that file in different ways including `required` and `from...` in example.js but nothing was successful. I do suspect there are couple of problems here but I cannot pinpoint them. Could you help?

Comment: That's not how you write [ESM modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Comment: This is how I have it written. It is not my file, I just need to write an example site with that. It is successfully imported in other projects using webpack and as npm module, I'd like to do it as simple as possible.